# react css animation loop different on first iteration than rest

Tags: reactjs, css-animations

https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-brook-niuge

Having an odd issue that I can't seem to wrap my head around. I have a component that is supposed to loop through an array of words, swapping one out for the next in a continuous loop. I have this working fine, but with one issue: the very first time this is run, every word shows up at once. I can't seem to understand why this is.

[image]

At a high level, here's how the component works. I set the state currentIndex to 0, and each iteration increases the count, until the length of the word array is reached. Each word in the array gets an index value, and if the currentIndex === index (of the word), then it gets a prop 'isVisible'. Otherwise, it gets a prop 'isHidden'.

Here is the component in full:

```
const cdRotateIn = keyframes`
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  35% {
    transform: rotateX(120deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  65% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
`

const cdRotateOut = keyframes`
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  35% {
    transform: rotateX(-40deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  65% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
`

const Wrapper = styled.div``

const Headline = styled.h1``

const StaticText = styled.span``

const AnimatedTextContainer = styled.span`
  display: inline-block;
  perspective: 300px;
`

const AnimatedText = styled.b`
  opacity: 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;

  ${ifProp('isVisible', css`
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    animation: ${cdRotateIn} 1.2s;
  `)}

  ${ifProp('isHidden', css`
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    animation: ${cdRotateOut} 1.2s;
  `)}
`

const FlipAnimation = ({ words }) => {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0)
  const animationDelay = 5000

  useEffect(() => {
    animateHeadline()
  }, [])


  const animateHeadline = () => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setNextIndex()
    }, animationDelay);
  }

  const setNextIndex = () => {
    if (currentIndex < words.length - 1) {
      setCurrentIndex(prevValue => {
        if (prevValue < words.length - 1) {
          return prevValue + 1
        }
        return 0
      })
    }
  }

  const animatedTexts = () => words.map((word, index) =>
    <AnimatedText key={index} isVisible={currentIndex === index} isHidden={currentIndex !== index}>{word}</AnimatedText>
  )

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Headline>
        <StaticText>My favorite food is</StaticText>
        {' '}
        <AnimatedTextContainer>
          {animatedTexts()}
        </AnimatedTextContainer>
      </Headline>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}

FlipAnimation.propTypes = {
  words: T.array,
}

FlipAnimation.defaultProps = {
  words: ['bacon', 'eggs', 'waffles', 'spaghetti', 'holy mother of god!']
}

export default FlipAnimation
```

In my mind, this shouldn't be happening, since I have confirmed that initially, every array element except the first has prop 'isHidden'. For some reason, this is not preventing everything from being shown at once. To compound matters more, the animation works as expected following this initial issue.

Comment: your array elements dont have props

Comment: @DamianGreen thanks for your response. Can you elaborate on what you mean? I don't understand why the array elements would have props, since it's the component that should be receiving props, right?

defaultProps are ['bacon', 'eggs', 'waffles', 'spaghetti', 'holy mother of god!']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this before your return

```
if (currentIndex === index || currentIndex === index - 1)
```

its to render only if its the current or the previous one.

its running here https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-darkness-0gbh9

Comment: this is missing a return statement of null when the condition is not met, so its effectively skipping the render of the component entirely